# How to handle a dynamic table with dojo.query()

Tags: php, ajax, dojo

This is going to be a meaty question because I am not sure the best way to handle this.

I have a page that contains a number of dojo inline editors, to allow users to change values, when one entry had been changes a save button will appear to prompt the user to save the information.

The page has a number of rows, contained within DIV tags, which relate to a row in a database table.

```
<?php if($this->userjobdetails != null) : ?>

<?php foreach($this->userjobdetails as $employment) :?>
    <div id="employ_<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']);?>">
        <table class="employment-table">
            <tr>
                <td><Strong>
                        <span dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" editor="dijit.form.TextBox" onchange="markEmploymentForUpdate();" id="cmpy_<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']);?>"><?php echo $this->escape($employment['employername']);?></span>
                    </Strong>
                </td>
                <td align="left"><input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="rolestore" searchAttr="name" name="role" id="roleInput_<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']); ?>"  value="<?php echo $this->escape($employment['jobrole']);?>"></td>
                <td align="left"> 
                    <span dojoType="dijit.InlineEditBox" editor="dijit.form.TextBox" onchange="markEmploymentForUpdate();" id="jtitle_<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']);?>"><?php echo $this->escape($employment['jobtitle']);?></span>
                </td>
                <td width="15px;">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']);?>" name="employid" id="employid_<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']);?>"/>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/images/site/msg/small/msg-remove-small.png" border="0" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick="removeEmployer('emply_<?php echo $this->escape($employment['historyid']);?>')"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

When the user 'saves' the page I want to then using dojo.xhrPost post the data for the elements on the page, so that the database rows are updated.

How would I go about this, having multiple 'rows'??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`dijit.form.Form`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Form.html#dijit-form-form) — the second example shows how to validate a form and do whatever actions you like when user submits it. AFAIK, `dijit.form.Form` doesn't care how many fields it has, and collects them dynamically.